# Start sed from a specific coordinate in a dataframe (tab delimited) through gitbash

Tags: bash, perl, git-bash

I have several files where I want to apply this option, if available.

A colleague of mine developed a perl script to get the proportion of unique characters/strings in a file starting in a specific coordinate, it works like this:

```
$./perlscript.pl --f=<File.gz> --r=<row start> --c=<col start> > outputfile
```

Which is great, since it allows to process a variety of files and sizes.

After applying this script to a handful of files, I detected that a lot of those unique characters, came with a space after them.

This same colleague developed a script that replaces unwanted characters with others, the problem is that this script just replaces one option at a time, and if that unwanted character comes along with other wanted characters, it does not recognize the specific unwanted character, i.e:

to get "AB" and "CD", from "AB " and "CD ", I have to specify to the script to replace "AB " for "AB" and "CD " for "CD" individually.

I just want to eliminate the space  starting from a specific coordinate in a file, to not mess with the colnames and rownames.

It does not have to be exclusively with sed, it can also be a perl script or an awk function.

Comment: Are these actually TSV (tab-separated values) files?

Comment: yes, they are, they point is i want to do it recursively, because all those files are in different directories, I know I can subset the files and apply a simple sed function, but it will be time consuming

Comment: Do you want to just remove all spaces at the end of each tab-delimited field then?

Comment: Yes, without affecting the first column and the first row, since those are metadata fields.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to boil down to:

> Do you want to just remove all spaces at the end of each tab-delimited field then?
>
> Yes, without affecting the first column and the first row, since those are metadata fields

Assuming that you don't have to worry about any fields with embedded tabs (If you do, you'll want a solution with an actual CSV parser):

Skipping the first column and first row make it a bit more complicated, but it can still be done as a somewhat cumbersome one-liner:

```
$ cat a.tsv
foo     bar     baz
ab  bc  de
1   1   3
$ xxd a.tsv
00000000: 666f 6f20 0962 6172 2009 6261 7a0a 6162  foo .bar .baz.ab
00000010: 2009 6263 2009 6465 0a31 2020 0931 2020   .bc .de.1  .1  
00000020: 0933 0a                                  .3.
$ perl -pe 'if ($. > 1) { my @f = split /\t/; $_ = join "\t", $f[0], map { s/ +$//; $_ } @f[1..$#f] }' a.tsv | xxd
00000000: 666f 6f20 0962 6172 2009 6261 7a0a 6162  foo .bar .baz.ab
00000010: 2009 6263 0964 650a 3120 2009 3109 330a   .bc.de.1  .1.3.
```

You can see the trailing spaces in the fields other than the first line and first column in following lines have been removed.

If you want to edit a directory tree's worth of files in place:

```
$ find /path/to/the/dir/ -name "*.tsv" -exec perl -pi -e 'if ($. > 1) { my @f = split /\t/; $_ = join "\t", $f[0], map { s/ +$//; $_ } @f[1..$#f] }' \{\} \;
```

Comment: that definetly solved the problem in the situation of just one row and one column of metadata, sorry for asking this, but I'm not well versed in perl yet, how do I make the starting col row options dependable in a pair of variables?, because the number of metadata columns and rows vary greately.

In other things, when I was about to sleep I tought of a very simple solution:

 'sed 's/[[:space:]]*\t/\t/g' file >outputfile'